Почему __init__.py не видит секретный ключ?
Если вношу секретный ключ прямо в init.py то все ок:
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'qwerty'
from app import routes

Проверяю python test.py :
import app
print(app.app.config['SECRET_KEY'])

Но я хочу секретный ключ поместить в отдельный файл, например в config.py:
import os

class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'qwerty'

В init.py вставляю:
from flask import Flask
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object(Config)

from app import routes

И вывод python test.py : None
И ошибка на сайте на странице формы пользователя.
Понял как отдельным файлом:
в config.py просто вставить SECRET_KEY = 'qwerty'
а в init.py:
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
Но хочется с class Config оформить.

Используйте app.config.from_object(Config.SECRET_KEY )

Ругается: AttributeError: type object 'Config' has no attribute 'SECRET_KEY'

Мой косяк. from_object принимает объект, а не строку как я думал, но плохие новости для вас, ваш пример у меня работает без ошибок.

проверти внимательно ваш класс, и его импорт

пакет config установлен: $ pip list |grep config
config                 0.5.1 , а его import указан в init.py

Понял в чем моя ошибка:
config.py должен находится  в каталоге верхнего уровня(в папке проекта), не в папке app, где находится init.py

Нет проблемы в том чтобы config лежал рядом с app, но если app лежит в пакете, то и импорт внутри пакета нужно делать относительный (типа from .config import Config) или абсолютный, через имя пакета (типа from app.config import Config, если пакет у вас app называется)

Да, спасибо, понял
